# JQuery find input with a specific value

Tags: jquery

AJAX Data
 `{"status":"error","code":"mailList","email":["hello@world.com"]}`

```
// data from ajax request
var myData = JSON.parse(data); 

// check if emails exists
for (var i = 0; i < myData.email.length; i++) {

    // find the fields with matching value   
    $('#finalForm').find('input').each(function() { 
        if( $(this).val() == myData.email[i] ) { 
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid #E33244');
            $(this).after('<span class="errMsg">Oops! You have already referred this email. Please use a different email.</span>');

         } 
    });
}
```

In the above code, is there any alternative code to find the `input fields with matching value`. Since this section of code is not executing on Firefox 29 on Mac OS. Your help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are intended to check for only `textbox` values,  you can filter your selector to check for only text boxes.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myData.email.length; i++) {

// find the fields with matching value   
$('#finalForm').find('input[type="text"]').each(function() { 
    var elem = $(this);
    if( elem.val() == myData.email[i]) { 
        elem.css('border', '1px solid #E33244').after('<span class="errMsg">Oops! You have already referred this email. Please use a different email.</span>');
     } 
});
}
```

Do check the outcomes of `myData.email.length` and `myData.email[i]` for more clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
// data from ajax request
var myData = JSON.parse(data); 

// check if emails exists
for (var i = 0; i < myData.email.length; i++) {
    var elements = document.forms['fForm'].elements;
    // find the fields with matching value  
    for(var j in elements){
        if(elements[j].value == myData.email[i] ) { 
            elements[j].style.border = '1px solid #E33244';
            $(elements[j]).after('<span class="errMsg">Oops! You have already referred this email. Please use a different email.</span>');

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: There are other forms also on the page. The one i would like to use is `<form role="form" name="fForm" id="finalForm" method="post" action="#">`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
var formEmails = finalForm.find("input[type='text']").each(function () {        
    var el = $(this); // cache it
    if(myData.email.indexOf(el.val()) > -1) { 
        // whatever css stuff you wanna do when a dupe
        el.css("border-color", "red");

        // stop checking further if that's your requirement
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
});
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Et3Ld/2/) to see it in action. I hope I didn't misunderstand you.

Comment: Thanks for your code, but I would like to make it clear that the code I mentioned work fine on all browsers except on FireFox 29 on Mac OS. I need an alternate compatible code. That's it!